# Configure XML Diff VBscript to pass through more than one XML

Tags: xml, vbscript, diff

The below script has been written to compare two XML files, it has been designed to flag any differences irrespective of the positioning of the elements.

How can this tool be reconfigured to pull in and compare multiple XMLs in a single file location and compared against one XML?

```vb
Dim o_xmlDocObj1 : Set o_xmlDocObj1 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Dim o_xmlDocObj2 : Set o_xmlDocObj2 = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
Dim o_objFSO : Set o_objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim o_objShell : Set o_objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim o_Nodes1, o_Nodes2
Dim o_ChildNode1, o_ChildNode2
Dim w_Found 
Dim w_ReturnString1 : w_ReturnString1 = ""
Dim w_ReturnString2 : w_ReturnString2 = ""
Dim o_objFile

Const c_ForWriting = 2, c_ForReading = 1, c_ForAppending = 8
Const c_TristateUseDefault = -2, c = -1, c_TristateFalse = 0

P_File1 = InputBox("Compare File:")
P_File2 = InputBox("Compare to File:")
P_resultFile = InputBox("Return Result to:")

If Not o_objFSO.FileExists(P_File1) Then
    MsgBox "File does not exist" & P_File1
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

If Not o_objFSO.FileExists(P_File2) Then
    MsgBox "File does not exist" & P_File2
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

If o_xmlDocObj1.load(P_File1) And o_xmlDocObj2.load(P_File2) Then
    Set o_Nodes1 = o_xmlDocObj1.documentElement
    Set o_Nodes2 = o_xmlDocObj2.documentElement

    If Not (o_Nodes1 Is Nothing and o_Nodes2 Is Nothing) Then
        For Each o_ChildNode1 In o_Nodes1.childNodes
            w_Found = False
            For Each o_ChildNode2 In o_Nodes2.childNodes
                If o_ChildNode1.xml = o_ChildNode2.xml Then
                    w_Found = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    ' Check Attribute level if Ref and PAthis the same
                    If (o_ChildNode1.getAttribute("Ref") = o_ChildNode2.getAttribute("Ref")) Then 
                        If (o_ChildNode1.getAttribute("PathAll") = o_ChildNode2.getAttribute("PathAll")) Then 
                            w_Found = True
                            For x = 0 To (o_ChildNode2.Attributes.length - 1)
                                sAttrName = o_ChildNode2.Attributes.Item(x).nodeName
                                 avalue=o_ChildNode2.Attributes.Item(x).nodeValue
                                 If (o_ChildNode1.getAttribute(sAttrName) <> avalue) then
                                     w_Found = False
                                    Exit For
                                 End If
                             Next
                         End If
                     End If
                End If
            Next

            If w_Found = False Then 
                w_ReturnString1 = w_ReturnString1 &  o_ChildNode1.xml & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next

        For Each o_ChildNode2 In o_Nodes2.childNodes
            w_Found = False
            For Each o_ChildNode1 In o_Nodes1.childNodes
                 If o_ChildNode1.xml = o_ChildNode2.xml Then
                    w_Found = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    ' Check Attribute level if Ref and PAthis the same
                    If (o_ChildNode2.getAttribute("Ref") = o_ChildNode1.getAttribute("Ref")) Then 
                        If (o_ChildNode2.getAttribute("PathAll") = o_ChildNode1.getAttribute("PathAll")) Then 
                            w_Found = True
                            For x = 0 To (o_ChildNode1.Attributes.length - 1)
                                sAttrName = o_ChildNode1.Attributes.Item(x).nodeName
                                 avalue=o_ChildNode1.Attributes.Item(x).nodeValue
                                 If (o_ChildNode2.getAttribute(sAttrName) <> avalue) then
                                     w_Found = False
                                    Exit For
                                 End If
                             Next
                         End If
                     End If
                End If
            Next

            If w_Found = False Then 
                w_ReturnString2 = w_ReturnString2 &  o_ChildNode2.xml & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If P_resultFile <> "" Then
        Call o_objFSO.CreateTextFile(P_resultFile,True)
        Set o_objFile = o_objFSO.OpenTextFile(P_resultFile,c_ForAppending)
        Call o_objFile.WriteLine(Now)
        Call o_objFile.WriteLine("Compare File " & P_File1 & " To " & P_file2)
        Call o_objFile.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------")
        Call o_objFile.WriteLine("Scheme not exist in  " & P_File2)
        If w_ReturnString1 = "" Then 
            Call o_objFile.WriteLine("*NONE")
        Else
            Call o_objFile.WriteLine(w_ReturnString1)
        End If 
        Call o_objFile.WriteLine("Scheme not exist in  " & P_File1)
        If w_ReturnString2 = "" Then 
            Call o_objFile.WriteLine("*NONE")
        Else
            Call o_objFile.WriteLine(w_ReturnString2)
        End If

        Call o_objFile.WriteLine(Now)
        o_objShell.Run("notepad " & P_resultFile)
    Else
        If w_ReturnString1 <> "" Then
            Call MsgBox(w_ReturnString1,vbOK,"Schemes not exist in " & P_File2)
        End If

        If w_ReturnString2 <> "" Then
            Call MsgBox(w_ReturnString1,vbOK,"Schemes not exist in " & P_File2)
        End If

        If w_ReturnString1 = "" And w_ReturnString2 = "" Then
            Call MsgBox("Both files are the same")
        End If
    End If
    WScript.Quit 0
Else
    MsgBox "Fail to load XML file" 
    WScript.Quit 1
End If
```

Comment: You can improve your question by providing a [mcve]. Otherwise it may be off-topic for SO.

Comment: SO is not a free script (re-)writing service. Your question as it stands is way too broad. Try modifying the script yourself and come back when you have a *specific* question about something you can't get to work.